# Xcode 8.0 unable to retrieve userData from SKTileDefinition

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode8

Xcode 8.0  beta (8S128d)
iOS 10

I am trying to retrieve userData from SKTileDefinition but unable to get any return data.

I can retrieve the name with the following code -

```
    if let tileType = landBackground.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row) {
        tileDef = tileType.name!
    } else {
        tileDef = "Nil"
    }
```

but when I try to retrieve the userData with the following code I get nil -

```
    if let tileType = landBackground.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row) {
        if let data = tileType.userData?.value(forKey: "data") {
            tileDef = String(data)
        } else {
            tileDef = "no string data"
        }
    } else {
        tileDef = "Nil"
    }
```

I have confirmed userData is set for the tiles I am trying to return.

Has anyone managed to get get this feature working in Xcode 8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you initialize an NSMutableDictionary and assign it to the userData property instead of just trying to assign values directly to userData.

Here is an example:

Assign the data to dictionary and then assign to the tile definition.

```
let dict:NSMutableDictionary = ["data":"someData"]
let tileDef = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: 0, row: 0)!
tileDef.userData = dict
```

To read the values, you can call directly as follows.

```
let tileDef = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: 0, row: 0)!
let data = tileDef.userData?.value(forKey: "data")
```

NOTE: This example doesn't provide any structure for error correction and is intended to just demonstrate the concept.